SVG markers not showing correctly on qgis2web map
I see in previous questions that SVG is not supported in qgis2web. Has this changed? You can see in my QGIS map the SVG markers are clear, but not showing in qgis2web map.



I noticed that you have also opened an issue on github, let's continue the discussion there since I will have to answer you mainly. Here is the link https://github.com/qgis2web/qgis2web/issues/1115
